# How can I get count files in bucket to avoid memory leak?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using AWS PHP SDK, and I need to avoid memory leak when I get many files from S3.

I want to set limit. If bucket has more than 50k files I want to throw an exception. Does S3 has functionality to get count of files in bucket/prefix before I get all files from S3?
My current solution looks like this, but it's bad

```
     $documents = $driver->client->getPaginator('ListObjects', 
     $arguments)->search('Contents[].Key');
     if (iterator_count($document) > $limit) { // but this way got all docs to memory
            throw new Exception("We exceeded the limit");
      }
```

Comment: What is your actual goal? Do you simply want a count of objects in a bucket?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein if objects count in bucket is greater than 50k then return response about files limit.

Comment: _Why_ are you wanting to do this? Why do you want to have a file limit? What use-case are you trying to achieve, beyond merely saying that the limit is exceeded? There might be a better way to achieve your end-goal.